# parse hex file and decode byte by byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, codec, utf, cp1252

I have a hex file with extension .brt and having hex values in the range 00 - FF.
I want to parse the file and print byte by byte value in the command prompt.

I tried the below line of code:

```
file = open("file.brt", encoding='utf-8')
data = file.read()
```

this gives me error as:

```
Exception has occurred: UnicodeDecodeError
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I understand the error is because the value is more than 128. then i tried with utf-16, this gives some random value.
then i have tried with the below line of code :

```
file = open("file.brt", encoding='ANSI')
data = file.read()
for line in data:
    for char in line:
        print(char.encode('utf-8').hex())
```

The above code is parsing the data but printing some random value if the hex value is more than `128`. for example if the hex value is `FF`, then it prints `c3bf`

Comment: `encoding='utf-8` means you're expecting *characters* in the file (UTF-8 encoded). Is that appropriate? What's the source of the .brt file? It might be a binary format, so you should `open` in binary mode ('b'), see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: What do you call *a hex file*? Can you open it with a text editor (notepad, notepad++, vi, etc.) and see hex codes, or do you have to open it with a binary editor to see the hex codes **of raw bytes**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to open the file in Binary Mode, by changing the open-line to open('file', 'b'). Then you can process your file in Hex-values.